# Animation for progress update

Tags: android, listview, animation, progress-bar

I have a list view where I need to show the status of every item. The status is binary. Its either complete(green) or incomplete(grey)
When i open the screen containing the list, for those item the status is complete, the status bar should animate from left to right, filling up the space with green.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

psuedo code

```
 public class amieKusserArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
 {
        private final Context context;
        private ArrayList<statusListItem> values;


    public amieKusserArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<statusListItem> values)
    {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values); // change here
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
       return values.size();
    } 

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        }

        statusItem = values.get(position);
        if(statusItem!=null)
        {
           StatusBar statusBar = (statusBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusBar);
           statusListItem.setStatusBar(statusBar);

        }
        return convertView;
    }

public class statusListItem{
    StatusBar statusBar;

    setStatusBar(StatusBar statusB){
        statusBar = statusB;
    }

    animateStatusBar(){
       statusBar.startFillUpAnimation
   }
}
```

Inflate ur listview with adapter and list of StatusListItems. Then every statusListItem object in the class will have a reference to all of the statusBars in the corresponding layout. Then whenever you want, you can iterate through those and trigger the anim.